Does the Machine GUID change when cloning a VM?
When cloning a VM, does the registry value change?
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography!MachineGuid
Or does it stay the same?

It stay, use sysprep /generalize to make sure it’s alright

When cloning a VM, does the registry value change?
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography!MachineGuid
No, the value is copied as-is.

Appreciate it !
